# Cancel and resume a duplicity backup

Tags: backup, rsync, duplicity

Is there a way to cancel `duplicity` (running over `rsync` and symmetric gpg encryption) without messing up the running backup and resume it later (for example after rebooting the laptop) without problems?

Suppose for example that after starting a `duplicity` backup on my laptop I notice that it will take too long time and that I have to shutdown the laptop in a few minutes.

Comment: I didn't notice either of the answers describing how to *cancel* a backup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `duplicity` and `rsync`  `man`, you should try this if you stop during the upload (don't know whether it's safe during encryption):

```
duplicity --rsync-options="-P" other_args
```

Answer (score 10):

Duplicity 0.6+ will attempt to resume a previously aborted/failed/partial backup ([source](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/duplicity-talk/2010-02/msg00021.html)). The rsync options will not help, as duplicity encrypts each tardiff file as it it created, and deletes these not yet transferred files on failure.

The rsync options will allow it to resume a transfer if no encryption is in use.

Comment: More context: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=536361